# Java 3D Game Engine?

Tags: java, 3d

Recently I've been getting into [Minecraft](http://minecraft.net/), which is a 3D game made in Java. I've made a few 2D java games, without any external libraries or IDE's or anything.

What I'm looking for, is just some libraries. Not anything with a GUI, just libraries. Rendering *.obj files would be nice, antialiasing not a requirement.

Comment: Have you looked at jmonkeyengine ??

Comment: [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/features.html)! There isn't much more to say.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Lightweight Java Game Library](http://www.lwjgl.org/) yet? It sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This actually look like it was what was used to make minecraft!

Comment: LWJGL is a set of bindings for low level APIs (OpenGL, OpenAL, OpenCL). It does not contain any OBJ loader because that's not its role, some scenegraphs based on it (and on its competitor JogAmp) provide such loaders.

Answer (score 16):

[JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) is the best Java 3D engine I know of.

Comment: [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/features.html) can easily compete with it today.

Comment: yep, I would agree. This is a very old answer.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want a thin library abstracting the low level aspects, maybe have a look at [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/).

If you want an high level API or a real scenegraph, rather look at [JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation](http://tinyurl.com/mpuu8or), [JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/), [3DzzD](http://dzzd.net/), [Xith3D](http://xith.org/), [Java3D](http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/), ...